# Azure IoT Central Connect Real Device. (Connection String problems)

Tags: azure, iot, node-red

I am following the next tutorial to add new real device on Azure IoT Central.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/tutorial-add-device

I want to use a node red flow to upload data, using the Azure IoT Hub flow, but in the tutorial is not very clear how generate the connection string. I can not find the dps_cstr tool for Windows...

Do you know how I can generate the connection string to upload data from Node-Red to Azure IoT Central?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial has a mistake.
With the **dps-keygen** we can generate the connection String. I use, -di,-dk,-si

```
dps-keygen <args>
args:
-di:<deviceId> : device id
-dk:<deviceKey> : device primary or secondary key
-mk:<masterKey> : admin primary or secondary key
-si:<scopeId> : scope id
-mr:<uri> : model repository uri
-mc:<uri> : model capability uri. Leave blank if its value is similar to model rep. uri.
-mi:<modelId> : model id
```

[image]